# Workbox caches excluded html

Tags: webpack, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

How can i remove index.html from service worker cache using google workbox (workbox-webpack-plugin)?
Previously using sw-precache-plugin I just wrote

```
new SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin({
    dontCacheBustUrlsMatching: /\.\w{8}\./,
    filename: 'service-worker.js',
    minify: true,
    navigateFallback: '/index.html',
    staticFileGlobsIgnorePatterns: [/\.map$/, /asset-manifest\.json$/, /index\.html$/],
})
```

but it doesn't work

```
new GenerateSW({
    cacheId: 'my-app-name',
    importWorkboxFrom: 'local',
    skipWaiting: true,
    clientsClaim: true,
    navigateFallback: '/index.html',
    exclude: [/\.map$/, /^manifest.*\.js(?:on)?$/, /\.html$/],
}),
```

Html file doesn't exist in manifest file, but fetches from service worker every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try 2 things:

1. Update to latest workbox (I assume you don't need the `dontCacheBustUrlsMatching` anymore)
2. Remove the `navigateFallback` entry and check if it works